# Radio buttons and functions

Tags: javascript, function, radio-button

I am programming an inspection form. I have a lot of radio buttons and I want, when a button is selected, to allow another field to populate a point value.

For example, Radio button name = 2.5 Green. When this button is selected, I want a text field (name = 2.5 points) to have a number appear in said text field.

Comment: research this: document.getElementById('your-id').value=document.getElementById('another-id').value; and javascript onclick

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started into looking in the right direction.

```js
function update(val){
document.getElementById('textbox').value=val;
}
```

```html
Green <input type="radio" name="color" onclick="update(this.value)" value="I am green"/> Red
<input  type="radio" name="color" onclick="update(this.value)" value="I am red"/>


<input type="text" id='textbox' />
```